# two-table-over <+> functional relationship: maintaining referential integrity

Tags: postgresql, trigger, foreign-key, referential-integrity

I have three tables, the last two having a many to one relationship with the first, written here in SQL:

```
create table study (
    id bigint primary key,
    name text
);

create table treatment (
    id bigint primary key,
    name text,
    study_id bigint references study
);

create table visit (
    id bigint primary key,
    name text,
    study_id bigint references study
);
```

These are brought together into a session which ties a person assigned a treatment on some visit in some study like so:

```
create table session (
    id bigint primary key,
    person_id bigint references person,
    study_id bigint references study,
    visit_id bigint references visit,
    treatment_id bigint references treatment
);
```

What is the best way to make sure that for any row in the session table, the study_id, the visit_id, and the treatment_id all belong to the same study? I am working in a Postgres 9.x database. Check constraints can't refer to other tables, so maybe a trigger before insert and update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a (redundant) unique constraint on `(study_id, id)` on both the `treatment` and `visit` tables. Then let the foreign keys from `session` refer to these unique constraints by including `study_id` into the respective foreign keys.

Then your condition will automatically be satisfied.

The unique constraints are not quite as superfluous as they seem, because the foreign key constraint on `study_id` should be indexed anyway.

To put it into SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE treatment
   ADD UNIQUE (study_id, id);

ALTER TABLE visit
   ADD UNIQUE (study_id, id);

ALTER TABLE session
   DROP CONSTRAINT session_treatment_id_fkey,
   DROP CONSTRAINT session_visit_id_fkey,
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (study_id, treatment_id) REFERENCES treatment (study_id, id),
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (study_id, visit_id) REFERENCES visit (study_id, id);
```

Comment: I have put it into SQL.